# How to create a SharePoint List with AJAX functionality?

Tags: wss-3.0, list

In sharepoint, the entire page reloads to edit the smallest info.  Can something be done with a Sharepoint List using AJAX (Something similar to Google Tasks)?

i use wss 3.0

thanks!

-saumil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build a hybrid of a DataView/FormWebPart and SPServices to update individual items in a list asynchronously.

Comment: This was actually the use case that launched SPServices I believe.  :)

Comment: Do I have to do individually for each list or I can create a View based on AJAX? THX